# AT+CMGS - Can not excape text input mode

Tags: sms, telnet, putty, gsm, at-command

I am using PuTTY to connect to an [industrial cellular router](https://ep.advantech-bb.cz/support/router-models/detail/lr77-v2-libratum) , to send SMS via AT-Commands.

In PuTTY, I select Telnet and connect to the IP-Address of the router on port 23:

```
Router loging: root
Password: ****
# gsmat ATE1                         // turn echo on

OK

# gsmat AT+CMGF=1                    // switch to text mode (0 = PDU mode)

OK

# gsmat AT+CMGS=\"0664XXXXXXXX"     // "tel. number"
> Test message [ENTER]              // new line (expected)
> [Ctrl-Z]                          // nothing happens, also with Alt+0026, etc.
> [Ctrl-D]
> -sh: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
#
```

I normaly the SMS should send on **Ctrl+Z** (according to documentation, forums, etc.), but nothing happens.
So i tried the following:

- ASCII code: **[Alt+0026]** for substitute (Ctrl+Z), nothing happens, also with Hex: 0x1A
- **Copy and past [SUB] from Notepad++**, nothing happens (copy and  paste normal text into PuTTY works fine)
- [Ctrl-Y] as suggested in some forum, maybe because german keyboard layout (also nothing happens)
- [Ctrl-D], syntax error, input escapes, but of course sending failes

I also tried different tools like Hyperterminal, SSH from CMD, [Hercules tool](https://www.hw-group.com/software/hercules-setup-utility), ...

Has anyone an other idea how to escape this text input mode in this situation?

My goal is to send an SMS autmatically via an C# service and there I just add (char)26 to my input and it works.

```
inputString = message.Length > 160 ? message.Substring(0, 160) : message;
inputString += (char)26;
connector.Write(inputString);
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

[Screenshot: PuTTY connection settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t8E1.png)
[Screenshot: PuTTY terminal input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1UcN.png)

Comment: The error you get after Ctrl+D seems related to Telnet shell and not to modem failure. As far as I know, after CTRL+Z you should simply wait (it can take even tens of seconds), and get either OK or ERROR.

Comment: Are you able to connect directly to the serial port of the modem without using that shell utility? It's just to understand which component is causing the issue.

Comment: @Cubo78 yes Ctrl+D was just a last try to get out of the text input mode somehow. I already waited minutes after Ctrl+Z an _nothing_ happend. I am pretty sure that the 0x1A get written there, it's just not sent because of the text input mode

Comment: I do not use a serial port. I connect to the router via Ethernet TCP/IP. I can access the routers WebGUI via my browser for settings. Also reading messages etc. works fine. The problem is just that the "command" (Ctrl+Z) for sending the meassage does not get registered right i think. I thought that might be a problem of PuTTY, but after testing different tools (Hyperterminal, also SSH via CMD), the problem remains

Comment: I understand you are connecting through TCP/IP. But the modem usually can be reached (also) *physically*, and it usually can be done through a USB/Serial port that  you can find on the device.

Comment: Just two Ethernet ports unfortunately. I updated the link to the specific router in the question.

Comment: To be clear, sending a message works fine with my C# service, but for further testing I would like to also send the commands manually

Answer (score 0):

What I do is send SMS via PDU mode. It's a little more effort, but much better for automatic SMS sending.

Comment: which library do you use to convert text into PDU?

Comment: I implemented one myself.... it was for an embedded enviroment and I wrote it in C. It's not too difficult to write , though I'm sure there's likely to be some good libs for it

Comment: If the problem is the way in which `CTRL+Z` is interpreted by PuTTy, I'm afraid that using PDU format would not solve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

According to several Internet sources, such as [this one](https://defkey.com/putty-shortcuts) `CTRL+Z` is a shortcut that makes you

> Put whatever you are running into a suspended background process. Type fg to restore it

which seems exactly what you are experiencing: `CTRL+Z` character is actually never sent, and that's the reason why the modem never sends its response.

As far as I know, sending ASCII 0x1A (decimal 26) should be correctly recognized by PuTTY. But since you already tried it there must be some other issue, and a different attempt has to be done.
Fortunately, process suspend feature can be disabled: as shown in [PuTTY user guide](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-telnetkey) that functionality is called *Keyboard sends Telnet special commands*.

In order to disable it:

1. Open PuTTy Configuration
2. Category Connection -> Telnet
3. Unflag *Keyboard sends Telnet special commands* option

Comment: I looked up this setting and it seems it's unchecked by default.
I tried both ways but the result was the same.
ASCII 0x1A should be recognized without [ENTER] right?

Maybe I should try with another tool, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: No, sorry. Are you able to sniff data on the Ethernet connection? Just to be sure on what actually is sent to the device and what is filtered by PuTTy. Another question: have you tried by sending data in ASCII format WITHOUT any previous attempt to use CTRL-Z? Maybe, in the past, you could have tried the ASCII solution AFTER ctrl-z. In that case we know that it wouldn't have worked anyway because of the "suspended process".

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is associated with the SMSC number.
AT+CSCA="+SMSC number"\r\n solved the problem